# Primefaces selectbooleancheckbox not working in a column

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am developing a small one page web app. In it, I have a datatable which contains a column that's a boolean. I wanted to try to display it as checkbox. However it's failing when rendered. I am guessing it is the fact that the object needs to be rendered and checkbox is a boolean and hence failing. Though this looks like a bug unless I am missing a mark up somewhere. Primefaces 3.2.1, GF 3.1.1, JDK 7.

```
<p:column>
     <f:facet name="header">With Login
     </f:facet>
     <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{server.withLogin}" onLabel="Login" offLabel="Without Login"/>
 </p:column>
```

Error stack is this

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.primefaces.component.selectbooleancheckbox.SelectBooleanCheckboxRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectBooleanCheckboxRenderer.java:60)
at org.primefaces.component.selectbooleancheckbox.SelectBooleanCheckboxRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectBooleanCheckboxRenderer.java:53)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularCell(DataTableRenderer.java:571)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:531)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indicates that you've mixed multiple PrimeFaces versions in a single webapp of which the older one which doesn't have the mentioned method at all got precedence in classloading.

Cleanup your webapp's runtime classpath. You should have only one version of PrimeFaces.

Comment: Q: How did you figure that out by looking at the stack ?

Comment: The exception type and the message: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html

Comment: I looked at it and said "Well, I hit a bug". So I am guessing this is a side effect of having multiple jars and class loader screwing up. Any place where I can read up on this ? Thanks by the way :)